# Favorite Tags list error

Tags: bug, status-planned, bookmarks, feed, tag-filters

I'm trying to browse for questions having my favorite tags and it fails with the following error:

```
Oops! An error occurred while fetching questions for this filter.
Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded, and developers have been notified.
```

[Here](https://stackexchange.com/filters/46656/favorite-tags?sort=active) is the link.

"Activity" and "Newest" tabs are malfunctioning, but "Hot" and No Answers" seem to work fine.

**UPD**: RSS subscription for `favorite-tags` is not working as well. The last update is on noon PST, June 27.

The question is how can I overcome the problem? Not a big deal if I need to unmark some fav tag(s), but there's no debug information to experiment with.

Comment: Good catch, you can try to remove tags from the filter until you find the culprit. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, unfortunately the metric truckload of tags scenario doesn't work all that well at the moment (it times out in SQL, often).  We're working on a long-term fix for this (get rid of the SQL!) that's not far from complete and should resolve these issues.

I'll tag this as [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) until we switch tag sets over to the new engine.

Comment: Thank you Nick. Is there any way of quick-fixing the issue for myself, except turning off individual tags and seeing what happens?

Comment: @bytebuster - reducing the number of sites directly simplifies the query...but when I say we're working on it: that's hopefully today or tomorrow on switching over, so if you can hold out just a bit, we should have this resolved with no changes on your end.

Comment: Knock knock - just in case you switched already and just forgot to update here. :)

Comment: I have to say that RSS has came to life on Sunday (which was my biggest concern). The Web interface is still there.

Comment: Is the update still planned? The Web page still has the same problem (RSS seems to work fine AFAICT).

Comment: Knock knock... guess it was done already? :)